# Excel - pull cell values from across multiple columns into one column, based on cell colour

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I’m trying to work out if I can pull values out of cells across multiple columns in Excel, and stack them in one column.

For instance if cells A3, A5, B2 and C4 in a worksheet were all highlighted using conditional formatting, is there a formula to identify the highlighted cells and stack them into one column based on them being highlighted?

Comment: That will require a VBA solution. If you can implement VBA, then you may want to do a search with that tag. I know this has been done before. You may also want to add the VBA tag to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. So you say that A3, A5, B2 and C4 are highlighted, due to a condition. Now you want to copy those values, and those new cells should be highlighted, due to the already existing highlights. Why don't you simple apply the already created conditional formatting on those new cells?